# What is this 2x2 headless driver body part?

Tags: part-identification, piece-information

[image]

I found this Black 2x2 Piece which looks like a drivers torso, but I have no idea where it comes from.

Only found this piece, *[Part# 30599](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30599&name=Brick,%20Modified%202%20x%202%20Racer%20Driver%20Square%20Head%20(Undetermined%20Pattern)&category=%5BBrick,%20Modified,%20Decorated%5D#T=C)*, that looks kind of similar, but mine has no head...

[image]

Any ideas?

[image]

FOUND IT its Brick, Modified 2 x 2 Racer Driver No Head
Item No: x351

How can I delete the post?

Comment: Welcome to Bricks SE. If you found the answer to your own question, please do not delete it, but [self-answer](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) it.

Answer (score 5):

I just confirmed your own self answer, and yes, you are right this part is indeed

*[x351 Brick, Modified 2 x 2 Racer Driver No Head](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=x351&name=Brick,%20Modified%202%20x%202%20Racer%20Driver%20No%20Head&category=%5BBrick,%20Modified%5D#T=C)*

[image]

This unique piece appears only in 20 sets.  Look ***[HERE](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=x351&in=S)*** to see where yours might come from.